# android pagination with multiple textviews

Tags: android, pagination, textview

I need to implement pagination in my android app.   I have multiple textviews in my android application. I need to display it as pages in my UI.

Am adding textview dynamically to my scrollview layout. Inside my scrollview there may more than one Textviews with dynamically loaded texts with different height. I need to implement pagination with this. How can i achieve this, please provide me some ideas or working codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe user [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)? It provide you pages where you can apply fragment with any view you want. You can use it on part of screen.

[Simple tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/)